# XML Comments -- How (or where) do you create XML comments for your namespaces and library?

Tags: .net, namespaces, assemblies, sandcastle, xml-comments

I understand that if you `///` above a class, field, method, or property Visual Studio will start establishing XML-style comments for you.

However, where can I go to add XML comments for my namespaces and/or library...

For example:

- [.NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045.aspx)

  - [System.Collections Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145035.aspx)

    1. [System.Collections Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.aspx)
    2. [System.Collections.Concurrent Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx)
    3. ...

I'm not sure if those pages were manually created or if they were automatically created via XML-style comments being added in the proper locations?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156582/namespace-documentation-on-a-net-project-sandcastle)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on the tool you use to generate your documentation. With `NDoc`, I believe, you simply had to create a class called `NamespaceDoc` inside the namespace you wanted to document. The XML-Comment of that class would have then be used.

Since the question is tagged with "sandcastle", I assume you are indeed using it. If so, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156582/namespace-documentation-on-a-net-project-sandcastle) should give the details.

**Update:** OK, I just ([in that same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156582/namespace-documentation-on-a-net-project-sandcastle)) saw that apparently Sandcastle understands NamespaceDoc-classes as well. Somebody might want to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: i have doubt regarding this XML-Comment for namespace, do we need to create `NamespaceDoc` class for each of my classes in my whole project ? or do i missing something ? im not using "sandcastle"

Comment: You create one "NamespaceDoc" class for (and inside) each namespace in your project (that you want to document).

Answer (score 0):

To generate the xml file you need to turn it on in your project properties. It's the checkbox `XML documentation file` on the `Build` tab of the project properties.

If you turned it on and you re-compile the assembly an xml file will appear next to the assembly with the same name as that assembly.

You can then use a tool like sandcastle to create a helpfile for your code. sandcastle is actually a set of tools you can use to customize the whole process of generating help files. This path will require a lot of reading the sandcastle helpfile and tutorials.

There also is a tool burried in the examples folder of the sandcastle installation that lets you quickly generate a helpfile but offers less cusomization.

In the past i used a visual studio plugin called "DocProject" for a little while. I'm not sure if it still active but you can find it on codeplex if your interested: http://docproject.codeplex.com/

According to Microsoft the MSDN examples you refer to are not created by extracting the `///` tags from their source but that had more to do with splitting the programmers and documenters deparments then anything else.